# Custom UITableVieCell in main.storyboard using custom cell class and objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i am new to objective c. I am trying to create a custom UITableViewCell in a UITableView using a custom cocoa class. Below is the code of the custom class.

```
//customcellnow.h file
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    
    NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
    
    @interface customcellnow : UITableViewCell
    @property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *labelup;
    @property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *labeldown;
    @property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *labelimage;
    @end
    
    NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

//customcellnow.m file

#import "customcellnow.h"

@implementation customcellnow
@synthesize labelup,labeldown,labelimage;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

As i have read in stackoverflow i need to synthesize the properties in the customcellnow.m files which i do. So now lets go to the main view controller.

```
//mainviewcontroller.h file
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>



@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{

    NSMutableArray *creditList;
    NSDictionary *s;
    NSArray *keys;
    NSArray *values;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tabledata1;

@end
```

So above as you notice i use <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> in order to be able to populate my UITableView. In my mainviewcontroller i use

```
self.tabledata1.dataSource= self;
   self.tabledata1.delegate= self;
```

and i use

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

}

in order to start showing the data. I changed the UITableViewCell class to customcellnow through the main.storyboard options. This is how my UITableView looks

[image]

This is where i do not really understand how the Imageview and the two labels are going to be updated programmatically. There is no IBoutlet connected to them because xcode shows error because they are reusable items. Please give me an example on how the Imageview is going to be updated. **I need to implement this only in objective c.** Any help appreciated.

Comment: Select 'cell' under the table view in the middle pane.  And set its class to your custom table view cell.

Comment: I have done that. How i update the uilabel i created on the storyboard?